# How to write a text along a circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

Using TikZ, I would like to write a text along a circle, as in the example:
positive direction.

[image]

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}`. If you need something more specific, it would be most helpful if you would please post some code!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use the `decorations.text` library:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[-latex,blue,postaction={decorate},decoration={text along path,
text={Positive direction},text align=center}]
(4,0) arc [start angle=-60,end angle=80,radius=4];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

And if you want the text in the middle of the path (though it decreases readability):

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[decorate,decoration={text along path,
text={Positive direction},text align=center}]
(4,0) arc [start angle=-60,end angle=80,radius=4];
\draw[-latex,blue]
(4cm,0.8ex) arc [start angle=-60,end angle=80,radius=4cm-0.8ex];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I want the curved text but not the arrow?

Comment: @skan Then you `\path` but don't `\draw`.

Answer (score 16):

If the text is going to be over the path the `text effects along path` decoration allows a background fill for each character:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\tikz\path[draw=blue, -stealth,
  postaction={decorate,decoration={text effects along path,
    text={\ Positive direction\ }, text align=center,
    text effects/.cd, 
      text along path, 
      every character/.style={fill=white, yshift=-0.5ex}}}]
  (4, 0) arc [start angle=-60, end angle=80, radius=4];
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It is worth to say that the PDF produced in this way can easily converted to various formats by using pstoedit (http://www.pstoedit.net) and reused in any graphics software lacking this functionality.