# How to decorate a page border with text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

I would like to decorate a page border with text, using a specified font. Here, I am using `Augie`. This answer [How to write a text along a circle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/268642) provides some guidance. I set up a `path` which is a `rectangle` 2.0 cm from the edge of the page as offsets from `tikz` page nodes. However, the text does not follow the path, as illustrated by the image. Any guidance would be appreciated.

This is the MWE.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.25cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shadows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{emerald}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\noindent\path 
    [%rotate=190,
     draw=blue,line width=1.0pt,
     postaction={%
        decoration={%
            text along path,
            text={|\ECFAugie\huge\bfseries|
                {Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce cursus metus eget lorem ullamcorper auctor. Vivamus vitae porttitor urna. Nunc aliquet, lectus at gravida semper, tortor odio fringilla elit, et elementum tellus neque eu erat. Sed luctus facilisis ex, eu lobortis mi semper ac. Duis fringilla consequat sem, non interdum ante lacinia vitae. Maecenas vel volutpat urna, eu dignissim dolor. Proin sed metus ante. }
                },
           text align=fit to path,
           reverse path
           },
           decorate}]
       ($ (current page.north west) + (2.0cm,-2.0cm) $) rectangle ($ (current page.south east) + (-2.0cm,2.0cm) $)  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In response to @esdd's comments, I rewote the code like this, but now there is no text at all.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\noindent\path 
    [%rotate=190,
     draw=blue,line width=1.0pt,
     postaction={decorate,
                 decoration={text along path,
                             text format delimiters={|}{|},            
                             text={|\ECFAugie\huge\bfseries|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce cursus metus eget lorem ullamcorper auctor. Vivamus vitae porttitor urna. Nunc aliquet, lectus at gravida semper, tortor odio fringilla elit, et elementum tellus neque eu erat.||},
                             text align=fit to path,
                             reverse path
                            },
                }
           ]
       ($ (current page.north west) + (2.0cm,-2.0cm) $) rectangle ($ (current page.south east) + (-2.0cm,2.0cm) $)  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: I do not have your font. But you can try: `text={|\ECFAugie\huge\bfseries|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ... ||}`

Comment: @esdd I posted a revision which adopts your suggestion but no text is produced. It doesn't appear to be related to the font selection because the text does not follow the path if this is removed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Package `emerald` and the `Augie` font are part of MiKTeX. You can use

```
text={|\ECFAugie\huge\bfseries|Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce ... ||}
```

and add `remember picture,overlay` to the `tikzpicture` options.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,svgnames,dvipsnames]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.25cm,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations,decorations.text}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, shadows,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{emerald}

\pagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\path 
    [%rotate=190,
     draw=blue,line width=1.0pt,
     postaction={%
        decoration={%
            text along path,
            text={|\ECFAugie\huge\bfseries|
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce cursus metus eget lorem ullamcorper auctor. Vivamus vitae porttitor urna. Nunc aliquet, lectus at gravida semper, tortor odio fringilla elit, et elementum tellus neque eu erat. Sed luctus facilisis ex, eu lobortis mi semper ac. Duis fringilla consequat sem, non interdum ante lacinia vitae. Maecenas vel volutpat urna, eu dignissim dolor. Proin sed metus ante. ||
                },
           text align=fit to path,
           reverse path
           },
           decorate}]
       ($ (current page.north west) + (2.0cm,-2.0cm) $) rectangle ($ (current page.south east) + (-2.0cm,2.0cm) $)  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

running twice results in

[image]

Note that there is a warning, because there seems to be no bold version for font `Augie`.