# Text along the edges of a page

Tags: text-decorations

So I have been wondering how to run text along the perimeter of a page so that it wraps around and rotates accordingly: text runs normally along the upper age, then `turns right' at the upper right corner (so now it is 90 degrees rotated and we need to rotate the sheet in order to read it properly), turns left at the lower right corner and now runs upside down, and so on.

There will also be some text in the middle of a page.

Cheers!

Comment: If you manually break the text, no problem (use tikz).  To automatically break the text, you would need \parshape to set the widths and \vsplit to pull off individual lines of text.

Comment: TikZ with decorations.text can do that.

Comment: See also: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367665/how-to-decorate-a-page-border-with-text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tikz` with `decorations.text` to get

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\draw[decorate, decoration={text along path,text
align=center,text={|\sffamily|It has been argued that all codes written by cats
are catcodes. You may believe it or not. However, be assured that cats do not like
computers because they typically have a mouse attached.}}]
 ([yshift=-1em]current page.north west) -| ([xshift=-1em]current page.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `tikzpagenodes`, you can run the text around the text area.

Comment: Nice answer. To add color to the text, don't try to wrap the text with `\textcolor{blue}{...}`, but instead use the tikz way: `text color=blue`.